# Send value with jquery

Tags: jquery, submit

How can I send a value with jQuery? I have tried this:

```
<span onclick="doSomething()" value="3">Select this Shop</span>
<input class="my-shop" value="">
<script>

function doSomething(){

  var text = $( this ).val();

  $( ".my-shop" ).val( text );
}
</script>
```

My code does not work, and I don't know why.

Comment: what do you want to get `<input class="my-shop" value="" type="text">`

Comment: The attribute value is not valid for span, or the use you want to do is not OK, as Rino said you have to use a different attribute, but for your purpose i would use the data-name="XX" which was creating for this situations, technically the attribute value is not valid for the DOM validation. The way to recover a data-attribute is like $(elem).data('name')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

►The `value` you gave on `span` is an attribute. So you have to get the attribute using `.attr()`.

**Working Demo**

```js
function doSomething(elem){
  var text = $(elem).attr('value');
  $( ".my-shop" ).val( text );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span onclick="doSomething(this)" value="3">Select this Shop</span>
<input class="my-shop" value="">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try same functionality in different pattern. [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/zjo1y4vv/)

```
<span value="3">Select this Shop</span>
<input class="my-shop" value="">
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('span').click(function(e){
  $( ".my-shop" ).val($(this).attr('value'));
 })
});
```

If you have lot of `span` in the same page and wanted to target specific `span` then you can add class for jquery selector.

```
    <span  value="3" class="unique">Select this Shop</span>
   <input class="my-shop" value="">
    $(document).ready(function() {
     $('.unique').click(function(e){
      $( ".my-shop" ).val($(this).attr('value'));
     })
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `doSomething()` function `this` refers to global window object. You can check that by putting `console.log(this)` inside your function.

one way to implement this is using JQuery selectors.

```
function doSomething(){
  var text = $('span').attr('value');
  $( ".my-shop" ).val( text );
}
```

You can find more about JQuery selectors from [this link](http://jascripts.blogspot.com/search/label/Filters%26Selectors).